# slick-lightbox not working in rtl direction

Tags: jquery, css, slider, lightbox, slick.js

Using slick-direction which works fine in ltr but in Arabic locale my direction is `rlt` in which `slick-lightbox` is blank and not showing anything.

I search and find solution for `slick` in rtl cases but not find any solution for `slick-lightbox`.

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution for it?

Comment: yes i find its solution

Comment: can you please publish the solution?

Comment: sorry for late reply. I add answer of it

Comment: @DavSev check answer, I hope it works for you also :)

Answer (score 1):

I done it myself by changing direction in slick.js

In slick.js there is a `function Slick(element, settings)` method. In that I add `rtl:true`

```
pauseOnDotsHover: false,
respondTo: 'window',
responsive: null,
rtl: true,
slide: '',
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
speed: 500,
```

By this change it works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I gave up and eventualy used lighrbox from http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/. Thank you again.

Comment: thank for your tip, `rtl: true` working good but when I switch again ltr then it's not working. How to work all?

Comment: one with rtl: true and other with default and then you will add that file depend on your files

Comment: @HaseebAhmad you mean I have to add 2 file custom js for 1 callback js?

Answer (score 1):

just wanted to give a clear answer:
there is a way to pass options to the carousel, 
you can pass it like this:

```
$('.images-container').slickLightbox({
    navigateByKeyboard  : true,
    useHistoryApi: true,
    slick: {
       rtl: true
    }
});
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your slider didn't work when you used `direction:rtl` in your CSS
you should be use this code in your script tag in the HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slick({
        dots: true,
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000,
        rtl:true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

slick.js documentation states, "Note: the HTML tag or the parent of the slider must have the attribute "dir" set to "rtl"."